# mysql double data in searching

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone can tell me what is wrong with this

`$paramcari` is the value that needs to be search for, it should be the data with the a.status not 0 and not 2 but the filter doesn't work, the output always show all status whether it is 0 , 0 or 2... what did I miss?

```
$sql="select a.*, b.*, d.*,  e.*, f.*, j.*, k.*, DATE_FORMAT(a.tgldaftar,'%d %b %Y %H:%i') as tgldaftar,
      DATE_FORMAT(a.tglkeluar,'%d %b %Y %H:%i') as tglkeluar , i.*
      from daftar a
      INNER JOIN  pasien  b ON a.noRM=b.noRM 
      INNER JOIN  ranjang d ON a.idranjang=d.idranjang 
      INNER JOIN  ruang e ON d.idruang=e.idruang 
      INNER JOIN  kelas  j ON e.idkelas=j.idkelas 
      INNER JOIN  instalasi  k ON e.idinstalasi=k.idinstalasi
      INNER JOIN (select idjenispasien , jenispasien  from jenispasien ) f ON a.idjenispasien=f.idjenispasien 
      INNER JOIN rujukan i ON a.idrujukan=i.idrujukan and a.status !=0 and a.status != 2";

if($paramcari != ""){
    $sql.=" and b.nama like '%$paramcari%'  ";
    $sql.=" or j.namakelas like '%$paramcari%'  ";
    $sql.=" or e.namaruang like '%$paramcari%'  ";
    $sql.=" or b.idRM like '%$paramcari%'  ";
    $sql.=" or i.namars like '%$paramcari%'  ";
    $sql.=" or a.nodaftar like '%$paramcari%'  ";
}   

$sql.="ORDER BY a.tgldaftar ASC limit  $start,15   ";
```

Comment: Formatting your code properly shows some effort.

Comment: Put your conditions in `WHERE` clause not the `JOIN` conditions as you do it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search condition `and a.status !=0 and a.status != 2` is appended to the last inner join condition. It should be in a where condition instead. Change the last join to

```
INNER JOIN rujukan i ON a.idrujukan=i.idrujukan
where a.status !=0 and a.status != 2";
```

Also add braces to your search condition, because `and` has higher precedence than `or`

```
if($paramcari != ""){
    $sql.=" and (b.nama like '%$paramcari%'  ";
    ...
    $sql.=" or a.nodaftar like '%$paramcari%') ";
}
```

Comment: I was describing this point, your answer is OK so I give it +1